# NuGet says installed but reference has an exclamation mark

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

I've had this problem ever since time began.

I just checked all our source code into TFS and my coworker pulled it down on his machine.

We have NuGet package restore configured so when we build, it should download missing stuff and work. However his solution won't build because Entity Framework, Unity and Dynamic Linq are missing.

If I go to Manage nuget packages... on the broken project or the solution, they are listed, and the only option is 'uninstall'.

So they're there. But they're not working properly.

If I expand References they have a ! next to them suggesting they're missing or something.

I have no idea what to do other than delete the references, uninstall from nuget, then reinstall from nuget.

I've had to do this numerous times in the past to fix issues with nuget, and there simply has to be a proper way to configure this so I don't have to do it every time I download the source code on a new computer.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is normal if you don't check-in the packages into source control.  Do note that you must check-in the package config file. Start with [RTFM](https://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore), note the required version number and the opt-out clause.  If that all checks out then you'll need to figure out why the build events are not firing.

Comment: I think the issue is the opposite, after a lot of googling, I think the problem is that I have checked files in that I shouldn't have. My best guess is that nuget examines the folder structure of the packages directory and if the folder exists, assumes the package has been installed. But TFS strips out the dlls and leaves the folder structure intact. By deleting the packages folder it mostly fixed the issue. I just need to get TFS to play ball and exclude the packages folder from source control I think, which is harder than it sounds since the packages folder isn't part of the solution...